# Training and Test images must be of equal size! OpenCV Crash iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, objective-c++, face-recognition

I am using the fisher face recognizer. When I call the predict function the app crashes. This is what it says in the logs...

```
Face DetectedOpenCV(3.4.0-dev) Error: Bad argument (Wrong input image size. Reason: Training and Test images must be of equal size! Expected an image with 12000000 elements, but got 1296.) in predict, file /Users/Name/Desktop/OpenCVBuild/opencv_contrib/modules/face/src/fisher_faces.cpp, line 140
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.0-dev) /Users/Name/Desktop/OpenCVBuild/opencv_contrib/modules/face/src/fisher_faces.cpp:140: error: (-5) Wrong input image size. Reason: Training and Test images must be of equal size! Expected an image with 12000000 elements, but got 1296. in function predict

(lldb)
```

My training and test images are the same size (3000x4000). What is the problem and how would I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear about what is wrong.
You're training the FisherFaceRecognizer on images of size 3000x4000 but try to apply it to smaller images.

**tl;dr:**
The *quickest* solution to your problem might be to resize your training data to match your test data.

**Explanation:**
The FisherFaces methods computes a projection matrix *W* to project the input data onto a lower dimensional space in such way that data points belonging to the same class are tightly grouped together, while data points of different classes are well separated.
This minimizes class overlap and allows for better class separation / classification.
Since this projection matrix is calculated from training data it has a data specific size. So in order to apply the matrix to your test data, it must be of the same size as you training data.

Comment: My training and test images are both the same size. After I posted the question I realized that the problem might be that I am storing the images in assets.xcassets, since this file is meant for vectors and the app icon it might be possible that Xcode resizes the images automatically to 40x40 or something like that. I am currently testing this theory by leaving the images in the main bundle. I will report how it goes. Thanks for the suggestion @s1h

Comment: My theory was incorrect. I found the problem to be that after I initialized the image I was cropping the face out of the image and then running through the model. I am working on a program to resize that image from 40x40 to 3000x4000. Thanks for your help! @s1h